# Onion architecture: Services should be in core or infrastructure ? Why?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, domain-driven-design, infrastructure, onion-architecture

I write a web application in ASP.NET Core.
I have three layers: core, infrastructure and web.
In the core, I have domain models. In Infrastructure, I have Service and interfaces to them.

Should Service be in the core, if not why and if they should be, why?

Answer (score 2):

"It depends" on the nature of the service.

In Eric Evan's book, he describes "domain services", "application services", and "infrastructure services" as separate ideas.

Answer (score 2):

You can put Service Interfaces at Core and Service class at different project and map interface and services using dependency injection at startup of your web project.

i had uploaded my onion practice project to git. you can get reference from there.
[Onion practice project](https://github.com/drzoshi/onionbase/tree/master/Exo_Base)